# Is it necessary to use third party control to draw charts on android?

Tags: android, android-layout, charts

Is it necessary to use any third party controls to create a bar-chart,pie-chart,bubble-chart etc in android.If so what kind third party controls have i to use?Can any one please let me know about this concept with at-least one sample program.

Thanks for your precious time!..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) [AChartEngine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) is a charting library for Android applications. It currently supports the following chart types:

```
line chart
area chart
scatter chart
time chart
bar chart
pie chart
bubble chart
doughnut chart
range (high-low) bar chart
dial chart / gauge
combined (any combination of line, cubic line, scatter, bar, range bar, bubble) chart
cubic line chart
```

2) You can also use another library called [ChartDroid](http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/).

Comment: can you please send me at-least one example or sample android program working with chardDroid or AChartEngine

Comment: okay.i've downloaded that and i got one RAR file.Actually i am self learner to android,so can you please tell me how to use that file on my project

Comment: imported that downloaded rar file in your eclipse project

Comment: Okay.. now i imported that downloaded file into eclipse...can you please let me know the steps to create a static or dynamic chart in android?

Comment: Look at this example . http://coffeedrivendevelopment.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/achartengine-xy-date-plot-example/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use third party libraries, but this it's not necessary.

If you are feeling comfortable with Canvas drawing you can create your own custom view that draw any chart type you would like.

Of course reinventing the wheel is not the best idea, but sometimes searching for a library, integrating it correctly, and customizing the charts, may take you more time than if you would proceed to do it yourself.